# findstr not working in Java, How to fix it?

Tags: java, processbuilder, findstr

I'm working on a project and part of it must search words in some raw files of tagged text. For this, I'm trying to use the "findstr" function but It's been giving me lots of trouble.
The file contains text in spanish so in order to deal with the special characters I have to use the "findstr" function with some options.
I'm trying to run the command by ProccesBuilder and Process class but nothing It's happening.

I suspected that maybe there was a problem with the actual work directory so I changed It in the ProcessBuilder object that I have but with no results.

```
private static void findWordData(String filename){

   try{
       String procs = "findstr /g:" + filename + " spanishEtiquetado* >results.txt"; 
       ProcessBuilder proBuild = new ProcessBuilder();
       proBuild.command("cmd.exe","/c",procs);
       proBuild.directory(new File("resources/TextData/SPA/"));
       Process p= proBuild.start();
   } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("exception happened - here's what I know: ");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }
}
```

The expected result is that the command reads the word in the file after the /g: tag and then searches it through all the files that begin with "spanishEtiquetado". Finally, the results should be written in a file "results.txt":

Thanks for your time.

EDIT:
Ok this is weird.
As you can read in the comments, I created a new project so I could test things better and something weird It's happening.
Right now, I have the aux_string.txt, results.txt and the spanishEtiquetado file both in the root folder of the project and src folder of the project.
As code I have been testing two options:
First, the one that SuperMario48 posted a bit modified:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c findstr /g:aux_strings.txt spanishEtiquetado* >results.txt");
```

The second one is the one I was using before:

```
String procs = "findstr /g:" + filename + " spanishEtiquetado* >results.txt";
ProcessBuilder proBuild = new ProcessBuilder();
proBuild.directory(new File("src/"));
proBuild.command("cmd.exe", "/c", procs);
Process p = proBuild.start();
```

If the first one is executed the files that are located in the root folder are treated by the command and thus the results.txt file in the root folder is modifided with the wanted results.

Now, If I use my old code the directory change happens and a results.txt is written in the src folder but it's empty because the other necesary files are not readed, not even those that are outside the src folder.
I don't hace any idea of what is happening, any help appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to add the absolute path to your findstr executable

Comment: I tried it but there was no success. If I go to the folder in the CMD and I type the command as I have in the code eveything works as It should be.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this. Just another kind of executing an external process.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c findstr /g:" + filename + " spanishEtiquetado* >results.txt");
```

Replace your try block with that to test.

Comment: I ended creating a new proyect just to test solutions. I tried your code and there were no changes but then I added the files used in the commad to root folder of the proyect. I used you command an then It worked so It seems it has something to do with the paths. Problem is that I've tried relative paths with this command before and do not seem to work.

Comment: I the end It seems it was fault of the raw files . It looks that they era not consistent and sometimes work and other times don't. Still, thanks for the help.